# In IE6, how to float item to right without clearing it?

Tags: css, css-float, internet-explorer-6

In IE6, HTML is as under:

```
<div id="topmenu">
    <ul>    
        <li>num 1</li>
        <li>num 2</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="rightItem">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

The CSS is as under:

```
#rightItem {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    clear: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 340px;
}

#topmenu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 960px;
    height: 41px;
}
```

It is floating the itemRight to right side on the same line (first UL and then rightItem) in all browsers except IE6.
In IE6, it is CLEARING and FLOATING to the right. How can I fix it for IE6?

Comment: Please provide more source code. What do you have besides #rightItem?

Comment: What I have been able to find is that, it is the problem in Listing. The css for listing is as under:


#topmenu ul {
 clear: none;
 display: block;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 900px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

#topmenu ul li {
 display: inline;
}

#topmenu ul li a {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 12px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 13px;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 line-height: 41px;
 font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
 white-space: nowrap;
 color:#000000;
}

Comment: All the browsers (even IE6) render the code you gave same... And what are those brackets doing in the code?!

Comment: Well I tried your code and IE6 is rendering the same way all the new browsers are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that `#rightItem` *isn't* actually clearing, but that it's width is different (wider) in IE6, which is causing it to push down onto the next line.

Floated elements should always have a width specified; try doing that first and see what results you get. Without seeing more of your HTML or CSS this is my best guess, and I'm only guessing because I'm tired of typing the words 'post more code' into comment fields...

Comment: I have updated the html. I put the width and it is OK in other browsers but still appears the same in IE6

Comment: Perfect guess !... The width was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow:hidden; to #topMenu. Works in all browsers.

See: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html